# how to delete folder from git repo and remove it totally from history

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have this structure in my git repo

```
  Proj1/Dir1

  proj1/Dir2

  proj1/ Dir3
```

I want to delete dir1 and dir2 from the repo also from all history.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: There's probably no good way to do that for a large or complex repo. One way might be to create a new master/base branch without those directories, then rebase your other branches against it.

Comment: Duplicate.  Read the very bottom here https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f -r --dry-run  Proj1/Dir1 proj1/Dir2' HEAD
```

remove the `--dry-run` part to do it for real.